# Добавить существующий файл в QT проект из другого проекта указав путь

Tags: c++, c, qt

Подскажите, как можно добавить header файл в Qt проект из другого проекта указав путь к нему?

Пробовал добавить в pro файл следующими способами:

INCLUDEPATH = /C:/Users/user/.../header.h

INCLUDEPATH += "C:/Users/user/.../header.h"

HEADERS += 
../../../header.h \

в файлах проекта добавляю через:
#include "header.h"

Но в все равно выдает ошибку
header.h: No such file or directory

Comment: Там ожидается каталог

Comment: CMake лучше использовать конечно. Сами Qt'шники его за новый стандарт взяли. А qmake по сути просто как легаси остался.

Comment: Что значит ожидается каталог, как его добавить?

Comment: @megorit, а что же в "новом стандарте" даже нельзя файл в проект добавить из Projects?

Comment: @Pomador ну вы хоть гляньте в документ, что такое INCLUDEPATH

Answer (score 0):

Не правильно в ссылающихся файлах указывал include
Правильная комбинация
pro файл
HEADERS += 
../../../header.h \

и
#include "../../../header.h"